# Installation genieacs faild

Tags: easycwmp

I tried to install genieacs (ubuntu 16.04 64 bits)
I followed the instruction in [link installation genieacs](https://tr069.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/installing-genieacs-on-precise-pangolin/)
when I type the command **genieacs-cwmp** I get this error `module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/opt/genieacs/lib/cluster'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object. (/opt/genieacs/bin/genieacs-cwmp:8:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)`
**someone can help me !**
**Thank you in advance**
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgFeL.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check if the missing module file is present (/opt/genieacs/bin/genieacs-cwmp.js), if it is not, try re-running the npm install command; if it is present and you ran "sudo npm install", try using the --unsafe-perm flag.

Hope this is usefull for you.

Answer (score -2):

It seems to be related to node version.

For stable version (Currently 1.0.7) you need node 0.12.17, por alpha version 1.1.0, you need node 4.6.2. It may work with other versions, but I have not tested every of them.

Try to follow the guide I wrote for Debian 8.6 in https://github.com/zaidka/genieacs/wiki/Installation-in-Debian-8.6

Just choose if you want stable or alpha version, as each one requires a different nodejs version.